# Distributing $k$ candies to $n$ children

Tags: probability

I want to double check my approach to this question:

Suppose that we have $k$ candies and $n$ children where $k = n$. What is the probability that:

1. Exactly 1 child gets exactly 2 candies.
2. Any number of children get two or more candies.

For 1: My thinking is that, if there is one child getting $2$ candies, that means there is one child not getting any candies if $k=n$, so $(1-\frac{1}{n})^k$ would be the answer.

For 2: My thinking is that we just have to use the same logic and sum over different configurations of children not getting selected because $k=n$, so answer would be $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (1-\frac{i}{n})^k$

For $k < n$

1. I just have to switch the index because, if one child is gets two candies, there must be $n-(k-1)$ children not getting candies
   $(k-\frac{1}{n})^k$
2. $ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (\frac{k-i}{n})^k $

If $k > n$

1. $(\frac{1}{n})^2 + (1-\frac{1}{n})^{k-2}$
2. Is trivial because there is no configuration where no children gets $2$ candies.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: If a child gets three candies, for example, do you consider this child to get two candies, or no?

Comment: for question 1, its looking for child that get exactly 2 candies.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: My understanding is that you intended to ask:  1.  What is the probability that exactly one of the children receives two candies and no other child receives more than one candy?  2.  What is the probability that any child receives two or more candies?  If so, your answers are incorrect.  For the first question, choose which child does not receive a candy, choose which child receives two candies, choose which two candies that child receives, and distribute the remaining $n - 2$ candies to the remaining $n - 2$ children so that each of those children receives one candy.

Comment: is it wrong for k=n , k<n , k>n or all of them?

Comment: Writing/posing suggestion:  Don't write "Suppose that we have $k$ candies and $n$ children where $k=n$."  Instead, write "Suppose we have $n$ candies and $n$ children."  See why that's much better?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1., and k=n, your reasoning is wrong between the "that means" is right but it's not an equivalence. You can have 1 children that does not have candy and none that have 2.

For question 2, I mean if you're using result from question it's gonna be wrong. There is a simpler approach, you can think about the negation of this.
Question 2 is I think easier than question 1